# $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{2-x}\geq a$ has a solution with interval $\leq 3$. [Solve for "a"].

Tags: inequality, parametric, radical-equations

I need to solve this inequality. The first part of the problem was to solve for $a=3$ implies $x\in [0,2]$. This makes me think that I will somehow use this. 
I try to find the solution for the second part of the problem by squaring the inequality. I get $2\sqrt{(-x^2+2x)}\geq a-2$. This is equal to two systems:
$$\begin{cases}
a<2\\ x\in [0,2]
\end{cases}\quad\mbox{and}\quad
\begin{cases}
a\geq2\\ 4x^2-8x+a^2-4a+2\geq 0
\end{cases}
$$

What do I do know and is this actually correct?
Please excuse me for this awful editing but I am on mobile.
Also, there is no tag parametrical radical inequalities.

EDIT: I continued trying with the second system by finding the roots distance with the formula $\sqrt{D}/|a|$ but with no results.

Comment: Thank you. Let's see.

Comment: What does the title really mean? Which interval has to be "$\leq 3$"?

Comment: The interval between the solution of the inequality. Otherwise said, the distance between the "roots"

Answer (score 2):

Note that the function $f(x):=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{2-x}$ is defined in $[0,2]$, it is symmetric with respect to $x=1$, i. e. $f(1+x)=f(1-x)$, and it is strictly  increasing in $[0,1]$ (because $f'>0$ in $(0,1)$). 
Hence $f$ attains its maximum value $2$ at $1$ and its minimum value $\sqrt{2}$ at the endpoints $0$ and $2$.

It follows that the inequality 
$$\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{2-x}\geq a$$ 
has at least a solution if and only if $a\leq 2$ and the set of solutions is the interval
$$\left[1-\frac{a}{2}\sqrt{4-a^2},1+\frac{a}{2}\sqrt{4-a^2}\right]$$
when $a\geq \sqrt{2}$, and it is the whole domain $[0,2]$  if $a\leq \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Thank you. Now I am thinking on it.

Comment: $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{2-x}\geq a$ has at least a solution iff $a\leq 2$.

Comment: Does this mean I am going to have 2 cases - 1. X from 0 to 1 and 2 - from 1 to 2?

Comment: @Daniel, Please find my other answer:)

Comment: I finally understood - the graph is an arch!

Comment: @DanielHalachev Yes, exactly. This helps you a lot to find the solution of the inequality.

Comment: And the first part of the problem when I solve for a=3 makes me think that for a=3 the interval is going to be ≤√3

Comment: No, the inequality $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{2-x}\geq 3$ has no solutions at all!

Comment: And it turns out that I have made mistakes in my calculation of the first part of the problem. I get an equation for it: 4x^2-8x+1≥0. But difference between roots is 2√3! :-(

Comment: @DanielHalachev Check your calculations and compare them with the solution given in my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Now let's get on with the other problems from my homework...By the way, what grade is this for in your country?

Comment: @DanielHalachev I think that irrational inequalities are taught  in 11 grade, but I'm not sure.

Comment: BTW if you are new here take a few minutes for a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Many thanks to you and @lab bgattacharjee, too.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

As $a$ is real, $0\le x\le2$

WLOG $x:2\sin^2t,0\le t\le\dfrac\pi2$

Now $\sin t+\cos t=\sqrt2\cos(45^\circ-t)$

Comment: Thanks for helping but I'd rather not solve it with trigonometric functions. I find them confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If $y=\sqrt x+\sqrt{2-x},$

$y^2=x+2-x+2\sqrt{x(2-x)}$

Now $\dfrac{x+2-x}2\ge\sqrt{x(2-x)}$ as $\sqrt p\ge0$ for real $p$